# Different Lcb wait3 API flags meaning

Tags: c++, couchbase

I am using lcb_wait3 API with flag LCB_WAIT_NOCHECK along with lcb_store3 and wanted to know if the records are written successful. Since the record number is huge, i want to know exactly which record failed. Will this flag help? What does this flag exactly do? I am unable to figure out from the documentation provided.

I am trying to first register the callback during initialisation:

```
lcb_set_store_callback(inst, storeCallback);
```

then , calling lcb_store3() each time for all records and at last after the loop iterator for number of records end, and all lcb_store3() returns SUCCESS, calling lcb_wait3() like this

```
        if (lcb_err == LCB_SUCCESS) {
            lcb_wait3(inst->getInst(),LCB_WAIT_NOCHECK);
```

I want to know whether this LCB_WAIT_NOCHECK flag have any impact on finding the record failed to stored ? Also what happens if i use LCB_WAIT_DEFAULT flag instead.

DOCUMENTATION LINK: https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-c-client/group__lcb-wait.html#ga7df65a3352efcbe21042d4d00b596861